# Nginx in SSL mode no info in config file

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have verified that the current nginx.conf used contains:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
events {
worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

While default.cong (the only file in directory /etc/nginx/conf.d) contains:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
}
```

I cannot se anything related to ssl.

However, when I go to my domain, writing

```
www.example.com
```

doesn't show any page.

While going to

```
https://www.example.com
```

shows the page.

How is this possible? Is there somewhere else you can point a domain to foce SSL? Maybe at network level?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the /etc/nginx/sites-available/* folder for files? You will probably have a default file in their with configuration for you to modify.